# Botão para dar scroll up na página está a dar um load desnecessário

Tags: javascript, html

Boa tarde, criei um botão para dar um scroll up ná página sempre que o utilizador dá scroll mas sempre que clico no botão ele dá um load estranho.

Este é o meu script:

```
<script>
    // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
    window.onscroll = function () { scrollFunction() };

    function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
    function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
    }
</script>
```

O meu botão:

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top"><i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i></button>
```

Comment: O que é "_load estranho_"?

Comment: Quando clico no botão a página dá load, a minha intenção é fazer com que o botão dê apenas scroll para o topo da página sem nenhum load.

Comment: Uma ancora não seria mais efetiva?

Comment: Certeza que o botão está dentro de um form. Coloca `type="button"` nele. Aliás, se ele estiver dentro de um form, está errado. Deveria estar fora.

Comment: Obrigado Sam isso resolveu :)